# Capture template for org-roam-bibtex to keep notes in single file

Tags: org-capture, org-ref, org-roam

As the title says, I want to setup org-roam-bibtex so that I can capture notes for different papers/articles in a single file.
(I've asked iterations of this on the [org-roam discourse page](https://org-roam.discourse.group/t/capture-template-for-org-roam-bibtex-to-keep-notes-in-single-file/2196) and on the `emacs` [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/qq150i/capture_template_for_orgroambibtex_to_keep_notes/?) )

I have tried something like this

```
(add-to-list 'org-roam-capture-templates
         '("s" "entry work bib reference" entry
           (file "~/org-roam/org-notes/template2")
           :if-new
           (file "~/org-roam/org-notes/paper-notes2.org")
           :jump-to-captured t))
```

where `template2` looks like

```
* %^{title}
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: %(org-id-new)
:Custom_ID: %^{citekey}
:URL: %^{url}
:AUTHOR: %^{author-or-editor}
:NOTER_DOCUMENT: %^{file}  
:END:


- tags ::
- keywords :: %^{keywords}
```

This works OK for the first time I try to add notes by doing `C-c C-o n` on a `cite:paper` link.

The problem is that `paper-notes2.org` file itself gets assigned `:ROAM_REFS: cite:%^{citekey}`, for every new set of notes/papers that are added to the file.

That is, after using the capture template for two citations, the `PROPERTIES` drawer of **the file** looks like

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       c67e87ef-2e57-4104-9b03-445c41118cfa
:ROAM_REFS: cite:yalcinEagerExecutionVs2021 cite:quallsLecturesConformalField2015
:END:
```

The headline nodes are created as expected, but doing `C-c C-o n` on a citation leads me to the top of the file `paper-notes2.org`, rather than the headline for the appropriate notes.

Is there a way to fix this behavior?

More generally, is there a guide to creating **a capture template for a headline node** in `org-roam`? The `org-roam` manual is pretty sparse on this (as it is on everything).

I'm using `org-roam-version 2.1.0` on Emacs 27.2.

Comment: Have you tried opening an issue at the [org-roam GIthub site](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam)?

Comment: @NickD Ah cheers -- looks like someone has already [opened an issue](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/issues/1937) related to this.